# Floating Action Button centerDocked, overlapping any screen or dialogue?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

I am using animated icons in my `FloatingActionButton` (FAB) at bottom navigation bar. But `FAB` overlapping any page or dialogue open from the `BottomAppBar`, how can I resolve this?

When I open a new page with `Navigator.push`, `Navigator.pushNamed`, `modalBottomSheet` or a dialogue, the fab overlapping them. 
Only works when I use `pushReplacementNamed` to open a new page.

How can I show the `modalSheet` without the fab on it and a page using just `pushNamed`?

I use [this](https://github.com/bizz84/bottom_bar_fab_flutter) reference.

```
floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
        floatingActionButton: _buildFab(context, model),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
          color: CustomTheme.getThemeData(context).getAccentColor(),
          shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
          notchMargin: 4.0,
          child: new Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                onPressed: () => _showModal(),

              ),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                onPressed: () => {},
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

This is my FAB
[image: img]

And this happen when a show the modal or any page
[image: img]

Please I need your help.. 
I don't know what else to do. :-(

Answer (score 0):

If this is happening with the Modal bottom sheet then try to increase the elevation of the bottom sheet. Like this

```
showModalBottomSheet(context: context, builder: (context) {
  return AddressChangeBottomSheet(
      title: "Change Area",
      showAddress: false,
      cityAreaList: list, onAddressChangeSubmit: () {
    mainBloc.fetchUpdatedUser();
  });
}, elevation: 10.0)
```